# Script running correctly from crontab, but not from cron.daily

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron

I have a script containing the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

passfile="/root/.access/.backup.cnf"

if [[ -r $passfile ]] ; then
     . "$passfile"
else
     echo "Password file not found or not readable." > "dump.log";
     exit 1
fi

echo "Beginning dump on $SERVER_HOSTNAME" > "$DUMP_LOG"

databases=`$MYSQL -e "SHOW DATABASES;"
```

When I run it manually, or from crontab -e, then it works as it should.

However, when I put it in cron.daily and leave it to run on its own, then it returns that no databases were shown.

Why is that happening?

Comment: Please provide your cron entry and whatever you're looking at to determine "it cannot detect the passfile"

Comment: Also please indicate whether that is the entirety of your script - or whether it has a bash shebang line

Comment: Thanks. I added more of the script. I did some debugging as well, and it seems the problem is not it not detecting the pass file, but rather not able to use the .my.cnf, as there are no databases being returned.

Comment: Depending on what `$MYSQL` is, the `mysql` client may look for the user's `.my.cnf` file (since there were no specific database host, user or password specified on the command line).

Comment: Yes, it is mysql, and I have a .my.cnf file it's reading from when running. The script is working from crontab.

Comment: Perhaps its not finding the `.my.cnf` (if it's searching on `$PATH` or something).  I debug these things with a `printenv` in the file to see what's going on.

Comment: @Pat From whose crontab is it working from? `cron.daily` is run by root, AFAIK.

Comment: @Pat : Debug it with `set -x`. Also do a `echo $PATH` in your script.

Comment: @Kusalananda root crontab.